# Path has git but my bat file keep saying 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, git, batch-file

I made a small bat file to try and find the issue in a bigger bat file.

The issue is that the bat file keeps saying...

> 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command

However, git **IS** in my PATH variable AND I **CAN** go into CMD and type git status and it works. This issue ONLY happens when I have the following code...

```
setlocal
set PATH=%PATH%
git status
pause
```

If I do this instead, it works... (But I need to be able to temporarily append the PATH variable during the .bat files execution, so I can't just remove the set PATH portion...)

```
setlocal
git status
pause
```

Anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: could you do echo %PATH% just before you call git and see what the path is?

Comment: `%Path%` is your system path variable and `%PATH%` is your user path variable. Which one is `git` a part of?

Comment: @J.Titus %Path% is in my System Variables when looking in my Environment Variables window... There is nothing named PATH or Path in my User Variables....

Comment: So when you do `PATH=%PATH%` you're effectively setting `PATH` to nothing?

Comment: @dgorti When I print out %PATH% it doesn't show the same PATH variable stored in my System Variables.... Not sure why.

Comment: @J.Titus No, I just tested printing %PATH% and something is printing... But it's not what's in my System Path variable... and changing it to %Path% still prints the same thing (missing git)... but git is in the environment variable.. im so confused.

Comment: What are you appending to the path variable?

Comment: Thanks everyone, found the issue though.... See my answer.

Comment: Batch variables (except for `for` loop variables) are case-insensitive. `%PATH%` and `%Path%` are the exact same variable.

Answer (score 0):

use user/system environment variable and set path. Restart your system and it will work fine

Comment: I've already tried that (using System Environment Variable)... I still get the error and I need to be able to set the temporary path using the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue...

I have MySQL installed and it installed 2 paths into my Path variable... each with a & symbol.

This was causing issues when running operations with Path in a bat file...

The solution is to wrap each of the 2 MySQL path variables in quotes.

Comment: No.  You would just need to SET the path variable correctly when appending to the path. `set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\somefolder"`

Comment: I didn't test your solution... but even if it did work... Better to fix for all cases in one attempt than to fix for each individual case each time. (As your method would only fix it for this ONE bat file and would have to be repeated, if it works, with every bat file).

Comment: That's why you run that command from the command prompt instead of just in a script.

Comment: @SomethingDark, has a good point.  You should have seen your code throwing an error every time you tried to reset the path variable.